# PowerShell: Splitting by comma unless in quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to parse a string splitting on commas except when comma is inside quotes:

```bash
$teststring = 'Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4'
$tempsting = $null
$tempsting = $teststring -split ',(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)'

Write-Host $teststring
$i =0 

Foreach ($object in $tempsting) {
    Write-Host $i " " $tempsting[$i]
    #Write-Host $tempsting[$i]
    $i++
}
```

Outputs this:

```
Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4
0   Data1
1   Data2,"Data 3, more"
2   Data2
3   "Data 3, more"
4   "Data 3, more"
5    Data 4
```

What I want is this:

```
Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4
0   Data1
1   Data2
2   "Data 3, more"
3   Data 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a solution that involves manually parsing your string with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) but just in case going to post this as a PowerShell alternative that is more object oriented and uses [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7.2) to parse your string. By no means this is an efficient solution but seems to do what you're looking for.

```bash
$string = 'Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4'
$parsed = $string, $string | ConvertFrom-Csv
$parsed.PSObject.Properties.Value | & {
    begin   { $i = 1 }
    process {
        $delim = ''
        if($_.Contains(',')) { $delim = '"' }
        ($i++).ToString().PadRight(5) + [string]::Format("{0}$_{0}", $delim)
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1    Data1
2    Data2
3    "Data 3, more"
4    Data 4
```

---

If there may be duplicate data, meaning, `ConvertFrom-Csv` may attempt to create objects with same **Property Names** use this code instead:

```bash
$string = 'Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4, Data 4'
$parsed = $string | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (1..$string.Split(',').Count)
$parsed.PSObject.Properties.Value | & {
    begin   { $i = 1 }
    process {
        $delim = ''
        if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) { return }
        if($_.Contains(',')) { $delim = '"' }
        ($i++).ToString().PadRight(5) + [string]::Format("{0}$_{0}", $delim)
    }
}
```

Using `'Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4, Data 4'` as the example, the output would become:

```
1    Data1
2    Data2
3    "Data 3, more"
4    Data 4
5    Data 4
```

Comment: Thanks... that seems to work, but I need the quotes included on the 3 object

Comment: @DeanHughes I see, that can be done too but going to wait a bit to see if someone posts a fully [tag:regex] alternative for this before updating my answer.

Comment: @DeanHughes - Can you just add quotes around a value after you've used ```ConvertFrom-Csv``` if it contains a comma? Trying to parse a real csv file with regex is likely to hit a lot of unhandled edge cases - for example, what if your data has escaped quotes in it - e.g. ```Data1, Data2, "Data3, ""more""", Data4``` or unclosed quotes ```Data1, Data2, Data3, "Data 4```. ```ConvertFrom-Csv``` will handle these for you...

Comment: @mclayton yup I agree `ConvertFrom-Csv` is the easy way around it, since nobody posted a regex answer I've updated the code to do that

Comment: @mclayton no as the input data I receive will not have that

Comment: @DeanHughes - Fair enough. If you've got constraints on your data that mean it won't hit those issues then it's not a problem, obvs...

Comment: To simplify the code, you could use the input string as the CSV header: `$parsed = $string, $string | ConvertFrom-Csv` and then loop over the properties to add the numbers as you already do, but you can remove the line `if(-not $_) { return }`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I was looking at your solution here as the possible best one for what I need, but the ConverFrom-Csv fails if there is duplicate data (which I will expect to have).  Is there a way to force it to acccept duplicate data ?

Comment: @DeanHughes I would need an example of what you mean by duplicate data and how it fails, if you can add that to your question message me again and I'll look into it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon consider the string $string = 'Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4, Data 4'

Comment: @DeanHughes there you go, that was the code I had yesterday before the updates :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks this is awesome... last thing... If I want to set a variable equal to each output would I do it like this:  $var = [string]::Format("{0}$_{0}", $delim)

Comment: If you want to capture all output into an array you would do `$output = $parsed.PSObject.Properties.Value | ....` and then you can get each element by index or by filtering. If you want manipulate single elements during the loop then yes as your comment above @DeanHughes

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks so much... the "$output =" method works great for my needs and I think I am all set... I so much appreciate your help.  The method I proposed didn't work.  The variable wasn't set, so not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889800/45375) with a regex-based solution:

```
# Split the string into fields.
$fields = (
  'Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4' -split '([^",]+|"[^"]*")' -notmatch '^,?$'
).Trim()

# Output the resulting fields, preceded by their index.
$i = 0; $fields.ForEach({ [pscustomobject] @{ Ndx=($i++); Value=$_ } })
```

Output:

```
Ndx Value
--- -----
  0 Data1
  1 Data2
  2 "Data 3, more"
  3 Data 4
```

**Explanation**:

- The regex passed to the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator is somewhat *repurposed* in that it normally is designed to match what *separates* the fields, but here matches the *fields*, and by virtue of using a capture group (`(...)`), includes the "separator" matches in the output.

  - For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/iPbNf8/1).
- Thus, the resulting tokens comprise both the "fields" - which in this case are the actual separators - and the "separators" - which in this case are the actual fields.
  `-notmatch '^,?$'` is then used to filter out the actual separators to leave just the array of actual fields (that is, array elements that are either the empty string or contain just `,` are eliminated).

As an aside: The `-split` + `-notmatch` approach above is **really a [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) solution in disguise** (see [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72890511/45375)). Use of `[regex]::Matches()` is a more direct expression of the solution's intent, but comes with its own complexity, not least due to not using PowerShell-native features. Bringing the functionality of `[regex]::Matches()` to PowerShell in the future in the form of a **`-matchall` operator** has been green-lighted, but is still awaiting implementation as of this writing: see [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867)

Comment: thank you so much.  this looks like it will do exactly what I need.  Looks to me that

-split '([^",]+|"[^"]*")' -notmatch '^,?$'

was the key part

Answer (score 2):

[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) was faster with the [RegEx-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72890411/7571258). To complement, I'm adding a different variant. Instead of splitting the string, I search for each comma-separated field, which can be either quoted or unquoted.

```sh
$string = 'Data1,Data2,"Data 3, more", Data 4'

$i = 0 
[regex]::Matches( $string, '(?:"[^"]+"|[^,]+)(?=,|$)' ).ForEach{
    ($i++).ToString().PadRight(5) + $_.Value.Trim()
}
```

Output:

```text
0    Data1
1    Data2
2    "Data 3, more"
3    Data 4
```

- The RegEx patterns consists of two alternations `(pattern1|pattern2)`. First one is quoted string and if it doesn't match, unquoted string will be matched.
- [Demo and full explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lkVOxL/4). (Note that I had to escape `"` for regex101, although it isn't needed for PowerShell. This is because regex101 assumes use from C#. Please upvote [this issue](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/1838) if you'd like a true *PowerShell flavor* for regex101.)
- **This isn't a full-fledged CSV parser**. If you need to handle edge cases, such as embedded quotation marks, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889800/7571258), which presents a more robust solution.

---

As you asked for it in comment, here is a way to access the data fields directly:

```sh
# Create an array that consists of the matched group values
$data = [regex]::Matches( $string, '(?:"[^"]+"|[^,]+)(?=,|$)' ).Value.Trim()

$x = $data[0]
$y = $data[1]
$z = $data[2]
$w = $data[3]
```

Another, more concise way:

```sh
$x, $y, $z, $w = [regex]::Matches( $string, '(?:"[^"]+"|[^,]+)(?=,|$)' ).Value.Trim()
```

In these samples we don't have to use `.ForEach{}`, because of PowerShell's convenient [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: I think I prefer this solution best.  Can you help me understand how I can access each data in the array without the index value?  For example I want $x=Data 1 , $y=Data2, ect.

Comment: @DeanHughes I've added code samples that show how to do this.

Comment: @DeanHughes I've also improved the RegEx so we don't need to use `.Group[1]` anymore. You can see the updated [demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lkVOxL/4) for detailed explanation.